# Erro ao tentar executar um Update com Parâmetro no SQL

Tags: sql, pl-sql

Estou com um pequeno problema que esta sendo uma dor de cabeça.

Estou querendo dar um Update com um SET, onde envolve dois parâmetros concatenado.

Segue update:

```
update tabela_usin  usin
  set usin.peca =  &P1 || ' ' ||&P11
 where usin.descricao = &P2
  and usin.complem = &P3;
```

Ao executar aparece a tela para eu colocar os valores do meu parâmetro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Todas são "STRINGS"

Depois que eu do Ok para dar o update.

Ele retorna como 0 Rows updated

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No começo achei que poderia ser o ' ' que coloquei no meu set. mas por ventura não é isso.

No que eu estou errando??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eu coloquei um operador LIKE no meu Where

Assim resolveu meu problema

```
 update tabela_usin  usin
   set usin.peca =  &P1 || ' ' ||&P11
 where usin.descricao like '%&P2%'
   and usin.complem like '%&P3%';
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]